Strange behaviour of get data from object
I do something wrong, but I cannot see it.
I have a valid JSON (although the validator says so:
{
    "battery.level": 60,
    "channel.id": 1213793,
    "ident": "xx",
    "message.type": "V1",
    "peer": "xx",
    "position.direction": 0,
    "position.latitude": 1.3xx,
    "position.longitude": 1.3xx,
    "position.speed": 25
}

If i try to read the value of this object with the following piece of code in a function node

i get the following error:

What do i do wrong?
see above
code should be good..

When asking about code in function nodes, please post the actual code not a screenshot. Screenshots can be hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers and unsearchable.

This because the object key has a dot in it. You need to use the square bracket notation to access keys with dots.
var msg2 = {}

msg2.payload = msg.payload["position.speed"]

return msg2

p.s. it's normally better to reuse the input object rather than create a new one as it throws away all the other fields on the msg object which may be required by other nodes (e.g. split/join or http-in/http-response)
e.g.
msg.payload = msg.payload["position.speed"]
return msg


Thanks! this was the solution i looked for.

Please feel free to accept the answer (the tick icon) as this makes it show up higher in search results

Try renaming your properties and instead of "." try using "_"
Example:
from: position.speed to position_speed
Then access like this
payload.position_speed


Assume the JSON is coming from a 3rd party source and can not be changed

In that case you can initialize a static variable to hold the name of the property
var position_speed = "position.speed";
then access it like this - in JS
payload. + position_speed;
// having a third party sending data in that structure is somehow rare

@MachariaNyamu thanks for the suggestion, but this is not possible as the data comes from a 3rd party.
